# Flex Events flow in non hierarchy e.g via framework responder

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events, flex4

say an application has panel and panel has button and textField or textArea. we click on a button to hit a service say via cairngorm framework.

The Events lifecycle follows the capture-target-bubble cycle in the display hierarchy like the MouseClick event on button will call the handlers for the listeners attached to button and/or panel and/or application and/or stage since the flow moves in this direction.

How do the event on non hierarchy works e.g the result from the service fires a custom event DataRecieved. we have a listener attached to the panel/button for this dataRecieved event. How do this listener gets the information? how the event lifecycle comes into this picture?

Can anyone explain this?

Thanks!

Comment: Will you give us and example of what you would LIKE to accomplish? FYI event.target will let you know which object dispatched the original event (eg your *service* object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the concept of GlobalEventDispatcher to which we can attach listeners and dispatch from the same.

a ref from another question was helpful - [Flex Custom Event dispatching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902080/flex-custom-event-dispatching)
The important point is that - the instance of dispatcher must be same. we can keep a Custom Global singleton event dispatcher for our application or we can use stage/systemManager/FexGlobals.toplevelapplicaton for the purpose which might not be a good Practice.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a non-DisplayObject, the Event only has a target phase.  That means that only listeners attached to the Object which is identical to the Object in the `target` property of the Event work.  Hence, non-DisplayObject's can only dispatch Events to themselves.  At least that's how I understand it.

In [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662274/as3-event-bubbling-outside-of-the-scenegraph-displaylist) there is some discussion of writing custom EventDispatcher's that would enable a bubbling for non-DisplayObject's.

Answer (score 0):

If  you dispatch a custom event on a Flex UIComponent via `dispatchEvent`, the UIComponent takes care of bubbling the event through the display hierarchy, as long as the `bubbles` flag in the Event object is true.